# Flutter-Why is Audio players playing only 1 file for all files in a list view

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, audio-player

I have a list view of 5 different audio files from Internet, but anytime I play 1 it'll play the one for all the files and it's always going to play only the last audio file..
I deleted the last file that's always playing each time I click any of the play button and it's still playing he same deleted file anytime I click play button

How do I play the particular file I clicked on and it won't affect the others

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.